# How to make JUnit pass both when exception is thrown and when execution runs without exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, junit

I know a simple way to do it is like this:

```
try {  
     //perform something you expect no exceptions  
} catch (Exception e) {  
    Assume.assumeTrue(e.getErrorMessage().equals("Expected Exception");  
}
```

Is there any other more elegant way to make my JUnit pass both when **specific exception is thrown** and when **exception is not thrown at all** maybe with Exception.thrown ?

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the unit tests should have one certain outcome and not possible multiple results.

You can always mock external dependencies that may affect your test result.
One of the unit test best practices is that the tests have to be "Repeatable".

Running a unit test should be consistent with its results, that is, it always returns the same result if you do not change anything in between runs.

One practice/rule which is also followed by a lot of developers is to have only one assertion per test.

So maybe the best solution here is to try and make your test "Repeatable".

Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: A simple way to achieve this would be to make two tests I think, one for each case. This would make it possible to force the state to be consistent.

Comment: But the problem is that one of the two tests will fail. Because either the code will run with no problems or it will throw a **very specific exception** (eg. user already exists with that username)

Comment: That's why you have to use mocks or db fixtures per test (setup each test case). The tests should be independent too. One should not affect the other.

Comment: @ps138 Not if you set the state correctly, basic example: let's say you want to check if you received some data. You would simulate the data since you are only testing the check if the data exists in this test. in The one test you create a data object, so you don't get the exception, in the second test you don't so you get the exception. This will not change however many time you run it.

Comment: @ngiallelis but if I want to test a service with many **microservices** then I will have to make my code dependent anyways. 
Let's suppose we have a service about Payment Account.

In one test (**TEST1**) I will run the test createAccountService() to create the account and I will save the paymentAccountId into a variable, then in the next test (**TEST2**), I will use that paymentAccountId to test if the service getAccountDetails(paymentAccountId) is working properly.

So i use @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)

Comment: @ngiallelis can you also explain me what do you mean by the word "Repeatable" ?

Comment: No, that is the point, in this case the first test could influence the second test, which is a big no no. So, you mock every micro service that you are not directly testing, even the network connections, because you want it to be in the same state every time you test. You can never fully rely on network or such things, so you mock them.

Comment: @ps138 Repeatable = Running a unit test should be consistent with its results, that is, it always returns the same result if you do not change anything in between runs.

Comment: @NG. here is my dilemma.

• I can either make my services dependant to each other and test **one microservice of the Service in every separate test**  
• Or I can create independent tests that **I double and triple and multi-call the same microservices** ( because for example ... in order to call test the getAccountDetails(paymentAccountId) microservice, I need the paymentAccountId from another microservice).   

So, in the end, i have to chose between duplicate code(more than 2 times for sure) or to make my tests dependant.

Comment: that's where mocking comes in: you don't need to have the micro service running that has the id, you only need the id. so in you tests, you can set a specific fake id, you only need the result of the micro service call, not the service itself. Are you familiar with mocking? if not you should read up on that, I don't have a good link at hand, sorry!

Comment: @NG. I am familiar with the concept of mocking. But we are currently designing Integration Testing. So in this phase, we need the actual service response because this is what we are testing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

```
@Test(expected=ExceptionType.class)
public void runTest(){
    // your code here
}
```

Or if you want to inspect the Exception further, [ExpectedException](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html).

```
@Rule ExpectedException exception= ExpectedException.none();

@Test
public void runTest(){
    // your code here
    exception.expect(NullPointerException.class);
    exception.expectMessage("your expected Message");
}
```

EDIT:

Both versions actually require the exception to be thrown; if you want to go the test go green in both cases, you could write your own `Rule`. But there's not much point to a test like this.

Comment: but i need a specific message not the Exception class

Comment: @ps138 added the `@Rule` option to the answer.

Comment: yes but this makes my test fail if the code runs smoothly.

Here is the error I get in the end:
**java.lang.AssertionError: Expected test to throw (an instance of com.###.###.###.###.exception.ClassException and exception with message a string containing "Device account with specified Uuid already exists")**

Comment: @ps138 Actually, I missed the part of your question where you want to make "JUnit go green both when specific exception is thrown and when exception is not thrown at all". That is not possible with this. You could write a Rule of your own, but I'd guess that's not worth it. Fix your code.

Comment: I want to test a service that currently faces a problem. Still, I want my test to pass even if the exception is not thrown in a different environment of the service that the exception is not expected to be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you don't do it in the same test.

Unit tests must test **only one thing** and must always have the **same result** if you ran it again **without changing anything**. In your case it is testing two different outcomes, so if it fails you don't know what is wrong. Was the error in the part of the code that handles the exception or in the part where it did not get an exception? Or even worse, if it passes you only tested one of the two things while the other one might be broken and you will not find out!

What you should do is split it up into two tests. One test for the case where the exception is thrown. You need to make sure that the exception *does* get thrown here.

The other test should be for the case where no exception is thrown. You need to make sure that the exception does *not* get thrown.